# Phones & tablets cannot connect to Windows Server 2008 RRAS L2TP VPN server

Tags: windows-server-2008, iphone, android, l2tp, vpn

I had installed RRAS in the server running Windows Server 2008 Standard. It's configured as a L2TP VPN server. The Windows and Mac OS X PCs can connect to the server without problem but the android phone and iPhone just don't connect.

I tried to google it around but I cannot find similar problem or solution. Does anyone have idea how do I solve this?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Hitting trouble attempting to get android l2tp clients to connect. Would appreciate any tips

Answer (score 1):

What authentication method are you using for the L2TP VPN? It's possible that your devices require a certificate issued from your CA to connect, but if your Macs and Windows PCs are connected to the domain then they'll have this by default.

Alternately you can try just using a PPTP VPN and seeing if that works.

Comment: Hi, Kovahr. Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mentioned it's using the IPSec pre-shared key. No, the Macs and Windows PCs are not connected to the domain.

I decided to use L2TP VPN because it's more secure. If I change it to PPTP VPN, everything works fine. Still, I do prefer L2TP. Any solution for this ?